# Editing etc/profile.d/foo.sh

Tags: environment-variables

Edited my etc/profile.d/foo.sh with the following

```
PXR_PLUGINPATH_NAME = "/usr/redshift/redshift4solaris/18.0.287:&"
```

but on boot I get an error message saying PXR_PLUGINPATH_NAME command not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the whitespace around the `=`

Comment: ... and you also (probably) want to `export` the variable.